# How to optimize an iterative function for big data analysis?

Tags: r, for-loop, optimization, while-loop

I have a problem of optimizing a model. My function increments the value of a variable (Dem) in an iterative process to arrive at the condition set in the "WHILE".

I had to use a "FOR's" and some "IF's", I know that makes the very slow processing in the R environment, but I have to do in R.
 
The variable P is the length of 10958 obs. The variables A and C has a length of 65511 obs.

Using system.time (myfunction), using only one element of the variables Area [1] and C [1], my computer takes 2.5 seconds to complete the process. But for all elements of Area and C will take 45 hours.

My professor said it's too slow, but I think for the amount of data is normal, there is a way to optimize this? Should a option optimize the function (PSO,DEoptim,etc) instead using WHILE?

```
myfunction = function(P,Area,C,Cap,Inc){      
  Vin<- Cap
  Q<-NA
  Ov<-NA
  Def<-NA
  Vf<-NA
  Vp<-NA
  Dem<-0
  Dem_100<-NA
  Fail<-0

  for (i in 1:length(Area)){        
    while(Fail==0){          
      Dem<-Dem+Inc          
      for (j in 1:length(P)){             
        #-----------------------------------------------------------------------#    
        ####################### Calculate Q #####################################
        #-----------------------------------------------------------------------#           
        if (P[j]==0){
          Q<-0
        }else{
          Q<-P[j]*Area[i]*C[i]
        }

        #-----------------------------------------------------------------------  
        ################################ Calculate Vp ##########################
        #-----------------------------------------------------------------------            
        Vp<- (Vin + Q) - Dem         
        if(Vp<0){
          Fail<-1
          break #stop For j and continue the while
        }

        #----------------------------------------------------------------------  
        ###################################### Calculate OV ###################
        #----------------------------------------------------------------------
        if (Vp>Cap){              
          Ov<-Vp-Cap          
        }else{ 
          Ov<-0
        }

        #---------------------------------------------------------------------
        ######################################## Calculate Def ###############
        #---------------------------------------------------------------------   
        if (Vp<0){ 
          Def<-0-Vp
        }else{
          Def<-0
        }

        #---------------------------------------------------------------------#    
        ################################## Calculate Vf ###########
        #---------------------------------------------------------------------#            
        if (Vp>Cap){
          Vf<-Cap
        }else{
          if (Vp<0) {
            Vf<-0
          }else{
            Vf<-Vp
          }
        }

        #-----------------------------------------------------------------------#    
        ################################## Update Vin ###########
        #-----------------------------------------------------------------------#            
        Vin<-Vf           
      }
      Vin<- Cap # Reset the var Vin for new j
    }

    Dem_100[i]<-Dem-Inc
    Def<-NA
    Dem<-0
    Vin<- Cap
    Fail<-0
 }
  return(list(DemGar100=Dem_100))
}
```

Test for time process

```
P<-abs(rnorm(10958))
system.time(myfunction(P = P,Area = 100,C = 0.8,Cap = 10000,Inc = 1))
   user  system elapsed 
   2.45    0.00    2.50
```

Comment: that'salotofcodeandbarelyanyspaces

Comment: you should explain what it's supposed to do rather than only give code. have you used a line profiler to identify some bottle necks? this looks straight forward to implement in cpp or python, have you tried that?

Comment: Once put spaces and complained, so this time I took. I will post again.

Comment: @rawr I know that will be a good in cpp or python, but i need do that in R. The purpose of this code is to increase the value of the variable Dem to the point that Vp variable is not negative. In other words find the bigger Dem value.

Comment: I think someone once said you can write Fortran code in any language. I, for one have little patience in reading such code when used as a problem description. You should spend the time to write out _in_natural_language_ a description, first of the data and then a processing workflow in  detail. (Furthermore is is NOT true that for()-loops are slow in R.) It is often true, however, the `if(){}else{}` in the middle of for-loops can often be replaced with more efficient functions. You are assigning to un-indexed variables so you will be overwriting the values with each iteration of the loop.

Comment: @BondedDust ok I will refine my question. I need just the value of variable Dem, so I don't need index the other variables.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough rep to comment, but since not a full answer it should go there.

Did you think to replace some ifs with ifelse? That should speed it up
Eg, you could rplace the whole j-loop with something like:

> for (i in 1:length(Area)){
>       while(Fail==0){
>       Dem<-Dem+Inc
>       Q <- ifelse(P==0,0,P*Area[i]*C[i])  ##note Q is a vector of length length(P)
>       ...

Also I think that Def seems to be never calculated (and Vf is always Vp when Vp<=Cap), because if Vp<0 you jump out of the j-loop and maybe even the while (you set fail to 1, but I do not know when R checks the condition, at end of the cycle?Or the beginning)

Comment: Thank you for your ans. I will try to replace and return the speed. You're right I can delete Def of code in this case.